# Issue about populating xml-file

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a workable script for updating an xml-file through Javascript, or at least I thought so up until just a moment ago.

```
function populate()
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","database.xml",false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

                newel=xmlDoc.createElement("Session");
                newtext=xmlDoc.createTextNode("Red");
                newel.appendChild(newtext);
                x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root");
                x[0].appendChild(newel);

                for (i=0;i<x[0].childNodes.length;i++)
                {
                    if (x[0].childNodes[i].nodeType==1)
                    { 
                        document.write(x[0].childNodes[i].nodeName);
                        document.write(": ");
                        document.write(x[0].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                        document.write("<br />");
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I change `x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root");` to, for example `x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("gallery");` nothing happens in the file so it's rather clear it got contact with the xml-file. But it won't print anything to the xml-file that I can see in either the web browser or when I download the xml-file, which makes me wonder how this actually works. I'm trying to learn this for a website I'm building where the gallery is using an xml-file.

At this point I only have `<root></root>` in the xml-document, so not much to copy there and this is all the javascript-code I got since I'm doing this on a test-site beside the main-project.

Can someone please explain or give me a nudge in the right direction for how to proceed with this.

Comment: What part isn't working? I can't seem to extract the problem from your question...

Comment: When I add the script to my page I get the document.write-output without any problem. But when I check the xml-file it's still empty. It's like it put everything there for the moment, but never saves the data.

Comment: How do I do that? This is all the javascript-code on the page btw, beginning to end. I haven't worked much with Javascript earlier, so I feel rather lost in this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a handler for the ready state change, and put your code for processing the response in there.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
       xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
       newel=xmlDoc.createElement("Session");
       newtext=xmlDoc.createTextNode("Red");
       newel.appendChild(newtext);
       x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("root");
       x[0].appendChild(newel);

       for (i=0;i<x[0].childNodes.length;i++) {
          if (x[0].childNodes[i].nodeType==1){
             document.write(x[0].childNodes[i].nodeName);
             document.write(": ");
             document.write(x[0].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
             document.write("<br />");
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain that part a bit closer? I tried it out, but it didn't even post the results from the input now.